# postgres - make a search by part of a word (node js)

Tags: postgresql, string-matching

I want to make a search by some part of a word from Postgres database. For example:
I have 3 columns in the table (`id,name,last_name`).

I want to make a route -->

```
/get-users-by-name
```

someone send me response ( for example `'An'`) and I look which name have the same start (and I get list with next names `"Anne,Andrew,Antony"` etc).

Can I make this search directly in the db or I should get all table from db and the parse it by `forEach` function?

Table like :

```
id : 1 ,name : Andrew , last_name : First
id : 2 ,name : Antony , last_name : Second
id : 3 ,name : Anne , last_name : Third
```

If I will pass input as `An` - I will get all list , because all started from `'An'`

Comment: This is unclear. In which of the fields do you want to search? Do you want to search for a substring match from the beginning of the field?

Comment: Sorry .. I want to make sort by name for example . I want to sort by beginning of the filed ( some part of field as I have explained on example above)..

Comment: `where name like 'An%'`?

Comment: it should depend on value ... this value is not a constant it can be 'A' , "An", Andrew etc .. After this request we should get only correct responses

Comment: Above I have passed some additional data for understanding